# Twitter like Form Submission using Ajax or Jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

I need a simple example of form submission very similar to Twitter.
How you type in a comment and click update and without the whole page refreshing, the comment gets added below on top of the rest of the comments.
I would prefer something in Jquery as my PHP project is already integrated with it.

Comment: try googling, there are tons of tutorials out there

Comment: I did spend a lot of time googling before posting the question. There are tons of examples talking about submitting form via Jquery. I was more interested in seeing how that comment is shown on twitter below without page refresh. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[See this pleae.](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/04/submit-form-jquery-and-ajax.html)**

Comment: @Gublooo: If you could have shown the code, it would have been much easier. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [an example](http://github.com/dorward/simple-ajax-demo) a while ago that more-or-less covers that. Getting data from a form is basic DOM, and you'll want to switch out the GET to POST since you are sending data rather then just requesting it.

Comment: Will take a look but its not simple though - I'm very new to programming - thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

I found these links for you:

**jQuery plugin: Simplest Twitter-like dynamic character count for textareas and input fields**

http://cssglobe.com/post/7161/jquery-plugin-simplest-twitterlike-dynamic-character-count-for-textareas

Or maybe

http://www.ajaxupdates.com/twitter-like-search-with-jquery-and-ajax/

Comment: These links dont explain form submission process of twitter - but thanks for sharing